# Calculate percentage of number of pixels of object detected to the total number of pixels in a picture

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I want to calculate the percentage of number of pixels of detected object to the total number of pixels in a picture in python. Many objects detected are detected multiple times so the total count of number of pixels of detected object is not correct.
[Test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcDFJ.jpg)

Comment: If you know how many times the detected object is counted, why not just divide the pixel-count by that number?

Comment: draw all detected objects on an empty image as filled white rectangles, then count all white pixels.

Answer (score 0):

In opencv get the shape of the image with `w, h = img.shape`. Then you can get the area of the image (number of pixels) by multiplying the `h` and `w`. The same thing is with the area of the pixels. When an object detection algorithm gives you the output, it's a bounding box coordinates. With that you can calculate the area (number of pixels) of each of the bounding boxes and sum them all up. Then just divide that sum with number of pixels in the image and multiply the result with 100.